# Autocomplete inside datagrid width problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

There are a lot of questions related to the problem of width in datagrid of MUI. But in none of them I found something that could help me with my case

My problem is that the items don't show correctly when text is long like it shows this image:

[image]

So, I have a custom autocomplete component

```
export default function CustomAutocomplete(props){
//..
return(
    <Autocomplete
                disablePortal 
                size="small"
                id="values-id"
                options={values.map(a => a[props?.keySearch])}
                sx={props?.sx}
                value={value}
                onChange={handleOnChange}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={props?.label}/>}
            />
)}
```

I call it from another component that use a DataGrid that have these columns :

```
    const userColumns = [
    { 
      field: 'title', headerName: 'TITLE', flex:1
    },
    { 
      field: 'services', headerName: 'SERVICES', flex:1, 
      renderCell: (params) => (
          <CustomAutocomplete
                title={"services"}
                keySearch={"libelle"}
                items={params.row.services}
                sx={{width:  180}}
           />
          ),
    },
//other columns
    ]
```

NOTE: when I use CustomAutocomplete outside DataGrid it works ok

Answer (score 2):

look in your DataGrid Component you must give `minWidth`  to that column data to be ok in views like this :

```
{
    field: 'user',
    headerName: 'Adviser',
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 200,
    headerAlign: "left",
    align: 'left',
    sortable: false,
    renderCell: (params) => (
        <Grid justifyContent={'flex-start'} alignItems={'center'}>
            <Grid sx={{mb: 0.5}}>
                {params.value?.['first_name']}
                {params.value?.['last_name']}
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                {lastLogin(params.value?.['last_login'])}
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    ),
},
```